# Authorization error: undefined 'No callback function was given.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, authorization

So I'm currently taking a React course, and I'm having trouble with the backend development. In Postman I'm trying to send an email and a password to the http://localhost:3900/api/auth. And when I look at my terminal in Visual Studio Code, it says "error: undefined 'No callback function was given.' ". I have bycrpt installed and I tried changing my bcrypt.compare() function to:

```
bcrypt.compare(
req.body.password,
user.password,
function (_err, validPassword) {
  if (!validPassword)
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");
  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res.send(token);
}
);
});
```

Yet I'm still getting the same error.

And here's what my original code looked like:

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
const _ = require("lodash");
const { User } = require("../models/user");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
const { error } = validate(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");

 const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
 if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");

 const token = user.generateAuthToken();
res.send(token);
});

function validate(req) {
 const schema = {
 email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
 password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
};

return Joi.validate(req, schema);
}

module.exports = router;
```

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is from the package your are using. As a matter of fact bcrypt-nodejs is currently deprecated. I suggest you move your implementation to bcryptjs.

Find more info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

With bcryptjs your original implementation will work like charm

Comment: Sorry it doesn't... Is there anything else you recommend?

Comment: Never mind @Emmanuel Sunday it actually does work. I must have forgotten to refresh it after implementing bcryptjs. Thanks by the way!.